# How to go one line back with perl

Tags: regex, perl, line

Could anybody tell me how it is possible in perl to go one line back in perl when you iterate over the text file. In instance if I see text in line and I recognize it and if it is recognized as an particular pattern I would like go back to previous line do some stuff and proceed further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally you don't go back, you just keep track of the previous line:

```
my $previous; # contents of previous line
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /pattern/) {
        # do something with $previous
    }
    ...
} continue {
    $previous = $line;
}
```

The use of a `continue` block guarantees that the copy is made even if you bypass part of the loop body via `next`.

If you want to truly rewind you can do it with `seek` and `tell` but it's more cumbersome:

```
my $previous = undef;    # beginning of previous line
my $current  = tell $fh; # beginning of current line
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /pattern/ && defined $previous) {
        my $pos = tell $fh;      # save current position
        seek $fh, $previous, 0;  # seek to beginning of previous line (0 = SEEK_SET)
        print scalar <$fh>;      # do something with previous line
        seek $fh, $pos,  0;      # restore position
    }
    ...
} continue {
    $previous = $current;
    $current  = tell $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
my $prevline = '';
for my $line (<INFILE>) {

    # do something with the $line and have $prevline at your disposal

    $prevline = $line;
}
```